# Apache/Django/cx_oracle raises 500 error when we switch one of the DB node from oracle RAC server

Tags: django, oracle, cx-oracle, oracle-rac

I deployed a `Django/Python` application at `Apache server`.
Application is connected with `Oracle RAC (Real Application Cluster) 19C DB server`, having 2 nodes.
I am using `cx-Oracle==8.2.1`. So the issue is, when we switch one of the node e.g make the one node up and other down the application starts giving 500 errors without any description.

Here is my DB settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'myrac.xxxxx.com/dbname:1111',
        'USER': 'usr',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxx',
        'TIME_ZONE': 'Asia/Karachi',
    }
}
```

Comment: What is exact error?

Comment: Does the application test for and reconnect broken database sessions?

Comment: @Ajay K. 500 internal server error and error response body is empty

Comment: You can check db connection using django management command.

python manage.py dbshell

Comment: @pmdba How to do it? Have to add 'CONN_HEALTH_CHECKS' in DB settings??

Comment: @pmdba python manage.py dbshell works perfectly fine on node switch. It connects to running node

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RAC with 2 nodes then unless both the nodes are not down your requests will be served. If you are switching from one node to other and if during the process of switching if no nodes are up you will most probably get **ORA-01034:** The Oracle instance is not available for use. Start the instance  or **ORA-12537:** TNS:connection closed or **ORA-01109:** database not open.If you are getting error 500 there may be some issue with your apache deployment and for exact issue you check your apache error logs.